Does this PCB have a specific name?
This is used as a giant button (8x8in). There is a copper sheet suspended overtop. The sheet then shorts the  tracks together to indicate an action.


The pattern is called "interdigitated" (digits as in fingers), and they're common in sensor applications but the button design itself does not have a name as far as I know. For switch applications it's more normal for the electrodes to be bridged by a carbon-filled elastomer that flexes (and can provide tactile feedback in many cases).
Here is an Adafruit polar design:

The elastomer keypad has a conductive ring (ring because an LED can go into the middle) to bridge the electrodes.

Remote controls typically use something similar, but the PCBs are massively cost-optimized and use a carbon filled ink rather than gold plating (and often instead of plated-through holes).

"interdigitated" - oooohhh   I like that.  I've done this a couple of times, but never knew it had a name.

It is an etched "interdigital" touchpad with 12 pairs of "interlaced" finger digits using track/gap ratio ~ 1.2 in a square pattern. It is used here as a resistive switch sensor but could be used as a capacitive sensor with calibration and ESD protection.
The R sensor is more predictable and the quality of the overlay greatly affects lifespan.
Anecdotal
It looks like a stack of coplanar microstrip traces like an MLCC capacitor.
I've seen drive-in car washes in Toronto where the elastomer was punched, punctured & mangled with keys because the carbon had a dead spot.
I have also seen grad student thesis presentations 15 yr ago done as a DJ audio console with "interlaced" patterns for all the controls such as disk wipe back/fwd, volume, fade, switch inputs player 1, 2, mic, volume etc.  They were not orthogonal digits but rather spiral, radial, linear etc to mimic mechanical DJ stations and some could detect positions for a wipe by sensing finger capacitance. There is nothing to wear out with a 8kV ESD protection with a solder mask for durability but gap ratios to reduce the nominal pF/cm of the "coplanar stripline capacitor" e.g. Track/Gap ratio < 0.5.
One is best to be current limited to 0V (PE ground) to raise EOS/ESD protection like a 10nF || 1 Meg wrist strap) Keyboards were not EOS protected in the 1980's and ESD guns could bypass the protruding LED's and latchup the CMOS. +/-8kV is a typical standard from a 3mm arc.
So you can describe this layout as "interlaced" (like old video interlace)  or "interdigital" track pairs ( almost like a dovetail joint)
Source: https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/how-to-create-various-dovetail-joints-3536486
Another memory in 1970 was a DIY design of wall switch that worked with a hand wave near the sensor to ramp up or down quick flip-flop to previous memory state using e-field reflections of the person's hand, analog + SSI logic and Triac.
